# Get the list of items in table

Tags: css, robotframework, playwright

This is regarding Robot Framework scripting.

I want to get the items in the column "Model Name" and then verify user clicks on column header to sort the items correctly.

How do I get the list of items? The items reside in `<span class="">` , sample HTML at below:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rPnx.png)

```html
<tr data-row-key="254104e218ea47f9879a270a3b688da3"
    class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">
<td class="ant-table-cell ant-table-row-expand-icon-cell">
    <button type="button"
            class="ant-table-row-expand-icon ant-table-row-expand-icon-collapsed"
            aria-label="Expand row">
    </button>
</td>
<td class="ant-table-cell ant-table-column-sort">
    <span><span class="">autotestmodel-0844-v1-8k</span></span>
</td>
...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try CSS selector on the "nth" child inside the 2nd `<td>` element within each row.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:nth-child(2)');
```

This will let you iterate over each `<td>` element, that is placed in the 2nd place in its `<tr>` container, and return a node list of all the relevant cells.
On this node list you can then iterate and use the inner text as you wish.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:nth-child(2)').forEach( item => {
  // do whatever you want with each node's text
  console.log(item.innerText);
})
```

Comment: I tried it at the browser console. it is working. How do I integrate it to Robot Framework?

Comment: added tag "playwright" would be good to know how to transform it to playwright format...so I can use it in Robot Framework.

Comment: @TestertwoDS to be honest, I don't know about Robot Framework. The question was a general CSS selector issue, so I helped with what I know... You'll have to figure out how to use CSS selectors in JS on your framework :)

Comment: yes I figured it out. will post answer

Answer (score -1):

Interact with the table by using selector `table tr td:nth-child(2)`
Get each of element then Append it to a list.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Browser
Library  String
Library  Collections
Resource            ../Resources/BrowserFunctions.robot
Suite Setup         Start New Browser
Suite Teardown      Close Browser



*** Test Cases ***
001-Models
    Open New Page To Server
    Navigate To Models Module

   ${elements} =    Get Elements    table tr td:nth-child(2)
   FOR   ${elem}   IN   @{elements}
      ${text}=    Get Text    ${elem}
      Log To Console    Model is:${text}
    END
```

To append all values to a list:

```
    ${elements} =    Get Elements    table tr td:nth-child(2)
    ${LexiconList}=    Create List
    FOR    ${elem}    IN    @{elements}
    ${text}=    Get Text    ${elem}
    ${new elem}=     Set Variable    ${text}
    Append To List    ${LexiconList}    ${new elem}
    END
    Log To Console    Lexicon List is: ${LexiconList}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).